# Excel Multi-Level Auto Sorting

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

Been trying for days to figure out how to do a two-level auto sort in VBA. I've managed to get a single level auto-sort working, but when I try adding a second level it overrides the first level sorting I did previously. Data is kept in Rows.

Here is what I am trying to set up to autosort

[image]

This is the VBA i have written right now for the 1st level or sorting which Sorts the Active? Column

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("A1").Sort key1:=Range("A2"), _
          Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, _
          OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
          Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Add key2 and order2

Comment: And drop the `On Error Resume Next`... that's just hiding potential errors.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it working with this now.

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("A1").Sort key1:=Range("A2"), _
          Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, _
          OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
          key2:=Range("B2"), _
          Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
          Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    End If
End Sub

Comment: Though Just noticed that it only sorts if Key1 is changed. It does sort Key2 correctly, but if I just make a change to Key2 it does not auto sort. Is there a way to fix that beyond just copy and paste of previous function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the new formula I wrote thanks to your comments. Seems to work. My problem before was I kept doing Key2 and Order2 as a new If function instead of as part of the previous one.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("A1").Sort key1:=Range("A2"), _
          Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, _
          OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
          key2:=Range("B2"), _
          Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
          Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    End If
End Sub
```